# installing egroupware 14.1 on ubuntu 14.04 running 5.5.9

Tags: php, ubuntu, project-management

fresh installation of egroupware 14.1 final on ubuntu server 14.04 gives following error;

> Cannot redeclare class egw in
>   /.../web/phpgwapi/inc/class.egw.inc.php on
>   line 37

up to now I have been using egroupware for project management without any problems. To find the source of this issue, I went into sources. placed an echo at top of class.egw.inc.php and found out that it is included only once. checked if a class with same name exists elsewhere with regex search and cannot find any. checked class autoloading functions. it is possible that I have some configuration missing (like mbstring) but in previous installations, setup script was giving warnings about them. This time it is only a blank screen with a error message in the logs.

Comment: this is probably a PHP issue :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731691/php-5-5-9-gives-error-when-subclass-is-declared-before-parent

Answer (score 0):

this is a PHP problem may be related to specific version. But this is the latest version for ubuntu 14.04 currently.

solution is to replace places of classes in /phpgwapi/inc/class.egw.inc.php. egw_minimal class should come before egw class.

after that, login screen appears in my installation.