# php 5.5.9 gives error when subclass is declared before parent

Tags: php

in my installation of php 5.5.9 on ubuntu 14.04 server, I get error when subclass is declared before parent.

testing.class.php

```
<?php
class mysubclass extends parentclass
{

}

class parentclass
{

}
```

myheader.inc.php

```
<?php
// empty header
```

index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once 'myheader.inc.php';
require_once 'testing.class.php';

echo "testing";
```

I get the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class mysubclass in /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/central/try/php559/testing.class.php on line 4

when I replace the places of parent and subclass in testing.class.php I do not get the error.

Comment: In my 5.5.11 installation this behavior doesn't occur (anymore).

Comment: this behaviour prevents egroupware running. there is such a construct in class.egw.inc.php. when replaced it works. I tried to upgrade PHP on ubuntu server 14.04, I guess it is not in repository yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after months, I found the source of the problem; it is not PHP, it is xcache. Since PHP 5.5 includes opcache, I was running both xcache and opcache on server. I uninstalled xcache and problem disappeared. I don't know which one is better, I prefer to use  what comes with PHP.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible explanation for this is that you have set up an autoloader. When PHP hits `extends parentclass`, it autoloads the file again to get its implementation, which also reloads `mysubclass`, which leads to the error.

You need to include/define/load parent classes before subclasses, there's no other way. Preferably every class should be defined in its own file as well.

Comment: Is the autoloading order not defined by PHP itself and can't be messed up by a user defined autoloader?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER PHP doesn't autoload anything by default, any autoloader is basically a user defined autoloader.

Comment: You're right, but the order in which PHP calls a registered autoloader to load files is done by PHP itself, isn't it? So PHP decides when the autoloader gets triggered for `parentclass` and at which point the autloader gets triggered to load `mysubclass`. So you can't mix up order with your own autoloader...

Comment: Sure. Something tells PHP to include this file. PHP parses the file. PHP hits a class definition it cannot resolve (`extends parentclass`). PHP invokes the autoloader. The autoloader includes the file. PHP parses the file, hitting a class definition it already knows about (`mysubclass`). Error.

Comment: Okay got it. So your second hint that you only should use one class per file is the key to most likely solve the problem in this case.

Comment: Having said all that, maybe this *is* a bug in a specific version of PHP and other versions are able to parse around this. I don't know, 3v4l doesn't show any errors in any PHP versions. However, it only seems logical that it errors one way or another, so the details are somewhat pointless IMO.

Comment: this is the updated PHP version on ubuntu 14.04 server. The problem was related with egroupware which contains such a construct and works after corrected (subclass, parentclass replaced).